# How to solve error when querying the .shp file to Excel?

Tags: python, geopandas, excel, pandas, path

I am making a Python code with `geopandas` and `xlwings`, what I do is colsulse .shp files from Excel, it works fine but when it reaches the last line of the code `wb.save (in_file)` where it should be saved The Excel workbook, Excel restarts or closes unexpectedly, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, besides that if I remove that line and when trying to save the Excel workbook manually, the same thing happens.

The code is:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
from pathlib import Path

#VINCULACION_S
in_file = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("VINCULACION_S.xlsm"))
wb = xw.Book(in_file)

#VINCULACION_SH_NUE
sht1 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SH_NUE']
in_features1 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VH_NUE.shp"))
shp1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features1, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp1 = shp1[['COLOR', 'INTERNO_DE', 'CLASE_DEMA', 'COUNT_AREA', 'SUM_AREA', 'SUM_LENGTH']]
shp1.insert(3, "CIV", '', allow_duplicates=False)

urow1 = sht1.range('B2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht1.range("5" + ":" + str(urow1)).clear_contents()
sht1.range('B2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp1

#VINCULACION_SH_ACT
sht2 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SH_ACT']
in_features2 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VH_ACT.shp"))
shp2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features2, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp2 = shp2[['COLOR', 'INTERNO_DE', 'CLASE_DEMA', 'COUNT_AREA', 'SUM_AREA', 'SUM_LENGTH']]

urow2 = sht2.range('C2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht2.range("5" + ":" + str(urow2)).clear_contents()
sht2.range('C2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp2

#VINCULACION_SH_CIV
sht3 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SH_CIV']
in_features3 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VH_CIV.shp"))
shp3 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features3, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp3 = shp3[['INTERNO_DE', 'CLASE_DEMA', 'MVICIV']]

urow3 = sht3.range('B2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht3.range("5" + ":" + str(urow3)).clear_contents()
sht3.range('B2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp3

#VINCULACION_SV_NUE
sht4 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SV_NUE']
in_features4 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VV.shp"))
shp4 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features4, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp4 = shp4[['INTERNO_SE', 'TIPO_SENAL', 'FASE_ACCIO', 'CONTENIDO1', 'CONTENIDO2', 'VELOCIDAD']]
shp4.insert(2, "CIV", '', allow_duplicates=False)

urow4 = sht4.range('B2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht4.range("5" + ":" + str(urow4)).clear_contents()
sht4.range('B2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp4

#VINCULACION_SV_ACT
sht5 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SV_ACT']
in_features5 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VV_ACT.shp"))
shp5 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features5, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp5 = shp5[['INTERNO_SE', 'TIPO_SENAL', 'FASE_ACCIO']]

urow5 = sht5.range('C2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht5.range("5" + ":" + str(urow5)).clear_contents()
sht5.range('C2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp5

#VINCULACION_SV_CIV
sht6 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SV_CIV']
in_features6 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VV_CIV.shp"))
shp6 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features6, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp6 = shp6[['INTERNO_SE', 'TIPO_SENAL', 'MVICIV']]

urow6 = sht6.range('B2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht6.range("5" + ":" + str(urow6)).clear_contents()
sht6.range('B2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp6

wb.save(in_file)
```

It throws me this error, after having unexpectedly restarted or closed excel

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Ejemplo\VINCULACION_S.py", line 72, in <module>
    wb.save(in_file)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 740, in save
    self.impl.save(path)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 552, in save
    self.xl.SaveAs(os.path.realpath(path), FileFormat=file_format)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 66, in __call__
    v = self.__method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.9\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9.py", line 46533, in SaveAs
    return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(3174, LCID, 1, (24, 0), ((12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (3, 49), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17)),Filename
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147023170, 'Error en la llamada a procedimiento remoto.', None, None)
```

***Update***: What I have tried so far and it works is to separate the code for each procedure of shp and sht, that is, I execute in a different .py selecting the excel sheet where the result will go and in this way it does it well, I am trying to add an instruction to the python code where in each # ... select the excel sheet to process and continue until saving.

Comment: You should add the error to your question as well.

Comment: Need to wait between calls (xlswings do remote calls to Excel API) according https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718037/error-while-working-with-excel-using-python (TLDR: use `time.sleep` to solve issue) Not sure why you introduce xlwings & associated issues as you can achieve the same with only pandas/geopandas. You can write each element to a particular dataframe e.g https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_multiple.html or element to a same dataframe & setting content position https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957441/putting-many-python-pandas-dataframes-to-one-excel-worksheet

Comment: @ThomasG77 I tried adding and using `time.sleep` in the code I show in the question body with no good results; I also have a code where I use only `geopandas` as `pandas.DataFrame` and result of `shp.to_excel (xlpath)` works well for me but it does not do it in real time like `xlwings` does, I will keep trying based on the links that you gave me, trying to adapt it to `time.sleep`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the error occurred because two or more sheets with rank in the code were activated, I solved it by adding the code in each # ... sht = wb.sheets ['name_of_the_sheet_to_process']. activate ()

I share the resulting and functional code, I hope someone will find this post useful

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
from pathlib import Path

#VINCULACION_S
in_file = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("VINCULACION_S.xlsm"))
wb = xw.Book(in_file)

#VINCULACION_SH_NUE
sht1 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SH_NUE'].activate()
sht1 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SH_NUE']
in_features1 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VH_NUE.shp"))
shp1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features1, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp1 = shp1[['COLOR', 'INTERNO_DE', 'CLASE_DEMA', 'COUNT_AREA', 'SUM_AREA', 'SUM_LENGTH']]
shp1.insert(3, "CIV", '', allow_duplicates=False)

urow1 = sht1.range('B2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht1.range("5" + ":" + str(urow1)).clear_contents()
sht1.range('B2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp1

#VINCULACION_SH_ACT
sht2 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SH_ACT'].activate()
sht2 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SH_ACT']
in_features2 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VH_ACT.shp"))
shp2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features2, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp2 = shp2[['COLOR', 'INTERNO_DE', 'CLASE_DEMA', 'COUNT_AREA', 'SUM_AREA', 'SUM_LENGTH']]

urow2 = sht2.range('C2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht2.range("5" + ":" + str(urow2)).clear_contents()
sht2.range('C2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp2

#VINCULACION_SH_CIV
sht3 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SH_CIV'].activate()
sht3 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SH_CIV']
in_features3 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VH_CIV.shp"))
shp3 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features3, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp3 = shp3[['INTERNO_DE', 'CLASE_DEMA', 'MVICIV']]

urow3 = sht3.range('B2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht3.range("5" + ":" + str(urow3)).clear_contents()
sht3.range('B2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp3

#VINCULACION_SV_NUE
sht4 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SV_NUE'].activate()
sht4 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SV_NUE']
in_features4 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VV.shp"))
shp4 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features4, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp4 = shp4[['INTERNO_SE', 'TIPO_SENAL', 'FASE_ACCIO', 'CONTENIDO1', 'CONTENIDO2', 'VELOCIDAD']]
shp4.insert(2, "CIV", '', allow_duplicates=False)

urow4 = sht4.range('B2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht4.range("5" + ":" + str(urow4)).clear_contents()
sht4.range('B2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp4

#VINCULACION_SV_ACT
sht5 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SV_ACT'].activate()
sht5 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SV_ACT']
in_features5 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VV_ACT.shp"))
shp5 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features5, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp5 = shp5[['INTERNO_SE', 'TIPO_SENAL', 'FASE_ACCIO']]

urow5 = sht5.range('C2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht5.range("5" + ":" + str(urow5)).clear_contents()
sht5.range('C2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp5

#VINCULACION_SV_CIV
sht6 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SV_CIV'].activate()
sht6 = wb.sheets['VINCULACION_SV_CIV']
in_features6 = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("INSUMOS/VV_CIV.shp"))
shp6 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(in_features6, ignore_geometry=True, index=False)
shp6 = shp6[['INTERNO_SE', 'TIPO_SENAL', 'MVICIV']]

urow6 = sht6.range('B2').end('down').last_cell.row
sht6.range("5" + ":" + str(urow6)).clear_contents()
sht6.range('B2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = shp6

wb.save(in_file)
```